# Does $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0& 1\\-1 &1\\1 &1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ define a surjective linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> True/False: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\-1 &1\\1 &1\end{pmatrix}$
>   defines a surjective linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Please can you tell me if this is right?

I found this on the internet (Wikipedia): A linear mapping is surjective, if and only if the transformation matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$ has a full row-rank: $\text{rank}(A)= m$

So the matrix has $3$ rows, we must get as row-rank $3$.

Forming this with Gauss, we get $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2\\ 
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, so our row-rank is $2$, which is not full rank.

Thus the statement is false?

Comment: The statement is indeed false. Note that you can also see this as follows: the vectorproduct $Ax$ can be seen as a linear combination of the columns of $A$ with coefficients the corresponding entries of the vector $x$. So applying your matrix to any vector gives a linear combination of two columns, which can never be the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (since that would mean that the dimension would be $2$ instead of $3$).

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is three dimensional, and so requires a basis of three vectors.  The (linearly independent) columns of $A$ form a basis for a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (since there are only two of them and the are linearly independent).  So what can you say?

Comment: This question looks an *awful* lot like another question, posted earlier today, about a 2 x 3 matrix defining an injective linear mapping. That one seems to have disappeared. And that's why I'm not going to answer *this* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{array}
\right)
=
c_1 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 \\
-1 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right)
+ c_2
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So you see that just a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is spanned, not the whole space.